# Geany - undefined reference

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, reference, undefined, geany

I am trying to compile C++ code with Geany.

Compile command: g++ -Wall -c "%f"

Build command: g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f"

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Person.hpp"

int main()
{
    Person p1(16);

    std::cout << p1.getAge();

    return 0;
}
```

Person.hpp

```
class Person
{
public:

    Person(int a);

    void setAge(int);

    int getAge() const;

private:

    int age;
};

inline int Person::getAge() const
{
    return age;
}
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.hpp"

Person::Person(int a)
{
    age = a;
}

void Person::setAge(int a)
{
    age = a;
}
```

Error:

> g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" (in directory:
>   /home/me/projects/Test) /tmp/ccxYmWkE.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to`Person::Person(int)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Compilation failed.

Before Geany, I only used Code::Blocks and everything worked fine. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can (and probably should) configure *Geany* to use a `Makefile` for GNU [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/); your build command is clearly wrong, you need to link several object files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious you didn't add `Person.cpp` to the compilation command. then it can not pass the linkage level.

Add `-o Person Person.cpp` to the build option after `g++ -Wall -c "%e" "%f"`. 
After all the compile command should be something like below:

```
g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" -o Person Person.cpp
```